# Is it possible to add a vertical line beside a paragraph with UITextView/UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm looking to build a `UITextView`/`UILabel` that allows for quotes to be distinguished visually. The most common way to do this is seemingly a vertical line to the left of the quoted portion.

An example would be [this article] from Daring Fireball, notice the line by the quoted portion:

[image]

How would I go about accomplishing this with `UITextView`/`UILabel`? I can figure it out in `UIWebView` using CSS, but unfortunately `UIWebView` simply won't work in this project (due to these quotes being in numerous `UITableViewCell`s). Similarly manually indenting paragraphs wouldn't work as it could appear anywhere in a block of text, perhaps the third paragraph, so I wouldn't necessarily know where to put it.

Comment: You could use normal UILabel/UITextView and add a vertical UIVIew of size 1 pixel. If u use autolayout u could set top and bottom of UIView with respect to UILabel/UITextView and set the horizontal spacing as well.

Comment: Did you read my last sentence? If so how would that work?

Comment: In that case let me know the answer too when u find :P May be drawing a line using beizerPath would work here. Need to calculate the paragraph height and indentations I think

Comment: Should be possible maybe with CoreText.